# Let SourceTree/Fork show changes instead of just displaying Old and New

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree, git-fork

I'm developing two iOS projects, when I edit storyboard file in first project, I can see the changes in git tool like SourceTree/Fork as showed in picture 1.[tap to see picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/emS97.png) It's good.

However, when I edit storyboard file in second project, git tool only gives me the Old and New files without any detail changes, detail on picture 2.[tap to see picture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gFzbc.png)

Here is the question:
I want the detail changes to be shown in the second project. what should I do?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should tell Git that `.storyboard` is a text type, not a binary type.

Comment: @matt - but both sets of files have `.storyboard` extensions, right?  So why the difference in behavior?

Comment: You have probably stored one file as UTF-8 (which Git and its ecosystem recognize as text) and one as UTF-16 (which is a peculiar Windows-only form, sort of).

Comment: Different repos can have different gitattributes settings. See https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes